# Matlab: `mesh()` plot with less number of grid

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, mesh, figure

Let's say `data` is a matrix of size `129 * 129`.

by using

`mesh(data, 'FaceColor', 'none', 'EdgeColor', 'black')`

we get something like

[image]

We can find that the **grid are quite intense**. I would like to have the same figure but with **less number of mesh lines**, something like

[image]

---

It is of course doable to plot a smaller `data`, for example `data(1:10:end, 1:10:end)`. But in this way, the plot are not accurate as before anymore.

Another example is `plot(..., 'MarkerIndices', ...)`. This can give you a plot with less number of markers without modifying the plot. https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/create-line-plot-with-markers.html

Comment: So you want less lines without drawing less lines? I have some troubles understanding your goal.

Comment: @Daniel yes, that's my goal. For example by using `plot(..., 'MarkerIndices', ...)` you can have less makers without drawing less points.

Comment: Do you perhaps want a [`surf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html) plot with *no* grid lines?

Comment: @gnovice yes. maybe we could `surf` plot first and then `mesh` with less lines?

Comment: @NathanExplosion: with MarkerIndices you only reduce the number of markers. With your mesh you are already at 0 markers. I guess you have to reduce the amount of data displayed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative approach is to use `plot3` to plot the mesh lines manually. That way you can plot each line smoothly using all the data points, but not have as many lines.

```
[X,Y,Z] = peaks(201);
step = 5;

plot3(X(:,1:step:end),Y(:,1:step:end),Z(:,1:step:end),'k')
hold on
plot3(X(1:step:end,:).',Y(1:step:end,:).',Z(1:step:end,:).','k')
hold off
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, I think this is a better option than just downsampling data in a mesh.

Answer (score 3):

I think your best option would be to create a [`surf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html) plot with no grid lines (showing a colored surface with the full resolution of your data), then overlay a down-sampled [`mesh`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mesh.html) plot. Something like this:

```
surf(data, 'EdgeColor', 'none');
hold on;
mesh(data(1:10:end, 1:10:end), 'EdgeColor', 'black');
```

You could also add some transparency to the `surf` plot to make the mesh visible through it:

```
surf(data, 'FaceAlpha', 0.7, 'EdgeColor', 'none');
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer from @David is good. In addition to his approach, we can also replace `plot3` with many infinitesimal `mesh`. The idea is to plot `mesh` for single vectors many times.

```
[X,Y,Z] = peaks(201);

tempz = NaN(201, 201);

tempz(1, :) = Z(1, :);
mesh(X, Y, tempz, 'EdgeColor', 'interp');
hold on

% plot x lines
for i = 2:10:201
    tempz = NaN(201, 201);
    tempz(i, :) = Z(i, :);
    mesh(X, Y, tempz, 'EdgeColor', 'interp');
end

% plot y lines
for i = 2:10:201
    tempz = NaN(201, 201);
    tempz(:, i) = Z(:, i);
    mesh(X, Y, tempz, 'EdgeColor', 'interp');
end
```

The original is

[image]

By using the snippet above, it gives

[image]

The benefits of this over @David's answer is that you can preserve all of the fancy properties of `mesh`, for example `shading interp` etc.